# How long should I keep my questions un-closed?

Tags: support, close-reasons

How long should I keep my questions un-closed?

I've already got some answers, but some interesting comments and even some additional answers are still arriving and I wouldn't want that to stop. On the other hand, the questions have basically been answered and I don't feel any urgent need to start a bounty on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Quick point of clarification: Selecting an answer does **not** "close" a question. Questions can still be answered and improved (and should be). Selecting an answer is just your way of indicating which answer best solved your problem. There's always room for more/better answers.*

Personally, I like to wait until no further answers seem to be immediately forthcoming.  I wait *at least* a few days to give everyone a chance to contribute and answer. Then I "select" the answer that I find most useful.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. Thank you Robert!!!

Comment: @brillant, You'll have to keep in mind that selecting an answer does not lock the accepted answer. If you accept an answer and later someone post a better answer, you can change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Eldros - didn't know that.  Thanks.